# Is there a way to delete folders from a web role after deployment?

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, delete-file

I have some files whose sole purpose is to be copied to the bin folder in a deployment. After built & deployed, these folders can be deleted from the web role.

Is there a way to automate this? Possibly with a startup task? What would the startup task look like?

**Update 1**

@Richard, thanks this is good info. I remember there being 2 folders, siteroot and approot. Will try just deleting the folders during App_Start.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly delete files in startup tasks, or do it from code in the 'OnStart' method of your class deriving RoleEntryPoint.

Is there any reason to delete the files? Are they doing any harm?

Comment: I thought access to the filesystem was read-only from the role. They are no doing harm per se, but I would like to delete them nonetheless.

Comment: No, you have complete control over the file system. However, any changes you make may be lost when the instance is recycled.